# Dropzone fileupload not working in asp.net MVC (VB.net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net-2010, dropzone.js

My project is asp.net MVC with VB.net. I am trying add feature of drag and drop a file. I have browsed several websites, also downloaded a code which is in C#. C# code works well. However, code in my project doesn't work. I've compared generated HTML code and they are same. Also tried by moving .css files into "/content" folder manually, adding link to .js manually in .vbhtml page [rather than script.render()]. But it didn't work. I'd tried with other JQuery file upload objects too. But none of them works. So, I thought perhaps the issue is with JQuery. So, I uninstalled it and installed it back. However, it didnt'help too. I am using JQuery 3.3.1.

Can you help ?

Main problem : Nothing happens when I drop the file. e.g. if I drop TXT file, browser just opens the TXT file as if I've dropped it in empty browser window.

HTML code is below :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="dropzone">
                <form action="/Home/Upload" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="uploader">
                    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
                        Drop files here or click to upload.<br>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS code is below. I can see alert "bingo" on page load.

```
    @section scripts

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("bingo!");
                Dropzone.options.uploader = {
                    paramName: "file",
                    maxFilesize: 2,
                    accept: function (file, done) {
                        if (file.name == "test.jpg") {
                            alert("Can't upload a test file.");
                        }
                        else {
                            //Show a confirm alert and display the image on the page.
                            alert("bingo2!");
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
    </script>


end section
```